# call custom phtml in product.info.details

Tags: magento2, layout, template, frontend, magento2.2

I call custom `phtml` in **`product.info.details`** but it's not working.

How I call:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/test.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
        <container name="custom.container" before="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="blockname" template="Vendor_Module::path/yourfile.phtml"/>
        </container>
      </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: No I don't want to custom tab i need to remove that tab insted of that i call custom phtml

Comment: Where you want to display your custom phtml file in product page?

Comment: Before product.info.details

Comment: Try my updated answer and let me know if not working.

Comment: I want to full width like product.info.details

Comment: Try my updated answer it will show phtml file before product.info.details with full width